# Deleting text leaves @string content in editText

Tags: android

I have a simple editText control. When I press delete it will move back but not remove the rendered text that is in the hint_status.

What is the reason for that?

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editStatus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonTweet"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="@string/hint_status" >

            <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

The view looks like this

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false);


        editStatus = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editStatus);
        buttonTweet = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonTweet);
        textCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textCount);

        buttonTweet.setOnClickListener(this);
        editStatus.setOnClickListener(this);

        defaultTextColor = textCount.getTextColors().getDefaultColor();
        editStatus.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int count = 140 - editStatus.length();
                textCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                textCount.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (count < 10) 
                    textCount.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                else
                    textCount.setTextColor(defaultTextColor);

            }
        });
        return view;

    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String status = editStatus.getText().toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "onClicked with status: " + status);

    if (v == editStatus) {
        editStatus.setHint("");
        editStatus.setText("");
    }

        new PostTask().execute(status);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the behaviour? What do you have written in the EditText when you press the delete key?

Comment: The text comes from the @string/hint_status in this case "Write something" the cursor moves back and the text stays there. If I write next text the editText control will contain the new text. But the screen will show the hint_status on top of the new text.

Comment: Still could not find the error in the code. Restarted with a new project and problem went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display hints, you have to use the `android:hint` XML annotation.

Your XML would look like this:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editStatus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonTweet"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/hint_status" >

            <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: I am using the same text string. But not showing it as a hint as you can see.

Comment: @user2130951 Well, showing it as a hint is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Showing it as a hint will give the same result. Except for the text I write is on top of the hint text. I want to clear the text when I enter the editText box.

Comment: @user2130951 Remove all your code that affects the `EditText`, you are doing something wrong there, and you don't need to manage anything. You can still have your `TextWatcher`, but remove the rest.

Comment: @user2130951 yes, you have an OnClickListener. If you try this with an unaltered EditText, you will find out it works.

Comment: It was added after I had this problem to try and remove the text programmatically there.

Comment: Done without any change. Added picture

Comment: @user2130951 Then you are doing something wrong unrelated to this. Once the EditText is focused, the hint gets removed.

Comment: You are right. Tried with an empty project. So then the question is. What is the real problem

Comment: You are right. Tried with an empty project. So then the question is. What is the real problem.

Comment: @user2130951 to isolate it just remove everything you do to the EditText and recode it again.